# Problema con acentos en VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, tildes

Tengo este codigo:

```
 If Me.Estado = "En estudio" Or Me.Estado = "Presentada a desarrollador / contratista" Or Me.Estado = "Presentada a cliente final" Then
    Me.comite_ofertas = "Sí"
End If
```

El codigo funciona correctamente, el problema es que no reconoce la tilde y mira lo que hace.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede ver, no se pone bien el acento.¿Alguna solución?